# Python dynamically override accessor

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class MBObject(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty()
    dictionary = ndb.JsonProperty(indexed=False, default = {})
```

What I want is if someone has an MBObject, like this:

```
obj = MBObject()
```

and they access any property, like this:

```
x = obj.author_id
```

that behind the scenes it does this:

```
x = obj.dictionary["author_id"]
```

So basically whatever property I access, it looks in the dictionary for that property instead of accessing the class's property.

And this should apply to setters as well:

```
x.author_id = 5
```

should translate to

```
x.dictionary["author_id"] = 5
```

Is this possible in Python, and if so, how?

(Please do not ask why, it would take too much to explain)

**Edit:**
Ok fine, here's why:

Subclasses are difficult in Google App Engine. It's impossible to create two different classed objects and run 1 query to get objects of different class types, even though they inherit from the same base class. You'd have to use a for loop to query, or use something they call a PolyModel, but that increases write costs.

So what I want is a dynamic class, without a predefined structure. I don't want to use the GAE Expando class, because all properties are by default indexed, and this makes writes very expensive. (You can set the default to be unindexed, but I want some indexed and some unindexed, and it doesn't provide that)

So my only choice is to throw all properties in a dictionary. And for convenience I thought I must just make it seem like it's object oriented, and hide the fact that the property is actually hidden in a dictionary.

Comment: Explaining "why" here might take a while but is nevertheless probsbly a good idea. There are a couple of immediately warning signs here. Besides using a dict literal as a default (bad idea; use None), your solution will involve overriding get/set related magic methods, which the nbd library is probably already doing pretty extensively...

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to use {}? It seems harmless. I don't understand what you mean by your second point..please elaborate..

Comment: @Triptych ok I updated the question with why

Comment: typically the dict literal is only evaluated once, so multiple MBObjects that use the dictionary's default value will be sharing the SAME dict instance and will be able to change each other's values. At the very least I'd test to make certain this isn't the case.

Comment: @Triptych but what do you mean evaluated once? How is that possible? If I create 3 unique objects, wouldn't it set that default property individually for every object?

Comment: this is a common mistake for Python programmers. There's more info here: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm. In short, this code would NOT create a "new default property" for every object. Both the dict literal used as a default AND the JSONProperty itself are basically singletons. In libraries like this, there is typically only ONE JSONProperty instance shared among all MBObjects which is responsible for marshalling data to and from the individual objects. These libs use every Python trick in the book (descriptors, metaclasses, etc) and you may not want to get in too deep.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this easily by using one of Python's magic methods:

```
__getattr__()
```

http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#access

Just define it in your object and give it the functionality you want:

```
class MBObject(ndb.Model):

  def __getattr__(self, name):
     if name in self.dictionary:
       return self.dictionary.get(name)
     else:
       raise AttributeError
```

Comment: Wouldn't accessing self.dictionary in getattr result in infinite recursion, or no?

Comment: Triptch has a good comment above mentioning this library probably already overrides this method - so keep that in mind.

Comment: Python will look for existing attributes before calling this.